# COUNT DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the Same Query Error

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have the following data:

```
countryId languageUsed
1          English
1          France
2          English
2          Spanish
3          Italian
1          Russian
```

When I query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT countryId) 
FROM languages
GROUP BY countryId
```

I get:

```
count(DISTINCT countryId)
1
1
1
```

Instead of just 3. When I remove the `GROUP BY` clause it will give me the right results.

Can somebody explain what is the reason for this type of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `GROUP BY` is taking several rows and turns them into one row.If this so, it has to know what to do with all the combined rows where there are different values. This is why you have two options for every field you want to `SELECT` which is either include it in the `GROUP BY` clause, or use it in an aggregate function so the system knows how you want to combine the field.

You're also experiencing a strict requirement of the `GROUP BY` clause. Which is every column not in the `GROUP BY` clause must have a function applied to reduce all records for the matching "group" to a single record such as `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG` and others.

If you list all selected columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, you are essentially requesting that duplicate records be excluded from the result set. That gives the same effect as `SELECT DISTINCT` which also eliminates duplicate rows from the result set.

Unless if you desperately want to use them both and get you're desired result, you can just use `SUM`. See below:

```
 SELECT SUM(countryId) FROM 
   (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT countryId)countryId
    FROM languages
    GROUP BY countryId
   ) AS A
```

**[SEE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ddd2/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `count()` and `group by` to the same `column` in a query if you only want to count distinct `countryId`. The result is like that because it distribute the returned `count(DISTINCT countryId)` to multiple `row` (because of the `GROUP BY countryId` clause) instead of returning only a single `row`. The code `count(DISTINCT countryId)` will suffice.